# UpdateTargetId ASP.NET Ajax...Where is it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

This is probably a silly question, but why am I unable to utilize Ajax in my project?

I should have all the necessary references:

> `System`
>   `System.Configuration`
>   `System.Core`
>   `System.Data`
>   `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`
>   `System.Data.Entity`
>   `System.Data.Linq`
>   `System.Drawing`
>   `System.EnterpriseServices`
>   `System.Runtime.Serialization`
>   `System.Security`
>   `System.Web`
>   `System.Web.Abstractions`
>   `System.Web.Extensions`
>   `System.Web.Mobile`
>   `System.Web.Mvc`
>   `System.Web.Routing`
>   `System.Web.Services`
>   `System.Xml`
>   `System.Xml.Linq`

I also added Ajax script references to my MasterPage, but this doesn't really matter at the moment since I cannot write code to utilize it.

Do I have to write a wrapper class that exposes these properties to my view? Or am I missing something else?

Thanks

code:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <%= Ajax.ActionLink("Test","AjaxTest",new AjaxOptions(UpdateTargetId = "test")) %>
    </p>
    <p id="test" visible="false">
        Test Text
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have referenced this assembly (which you obviously have give your list of `using` statements):

```
System.Web.Mvc.dll
```

and also make sure that you import this namespace as well:

```
System.Web.Mvc.Ajax
```

Comment: The application compiles with or without the import, and both ways I get this error when attempting to it: "UpdateTargetId does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0):

as stated above, add the System.Web.Mvc.dll to your project, add a reference to System.Web.Mvc.Ajax, and use the following js files:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to actually start using it.